# Cloud Function returns null on android app

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am calling a *Cloud Function* on *Android App* and the return value is *null*, it works fine when *onRequest* is used instead of *onCall* from browser, but when the function is called from Android App using *OnCall* it returns null

*Code:*

```
export const userExistsOrNot = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

const driver = neo4j.v1.driver("uri", neo4j.v1.auth.basic("usr", "pwd"), {connectionTimeout: 30 * 1000})

const session = driver.session()

  session.readTransaction(wrte=>{
    let r : any

    if(context.auth){
      r = wrte.run('MATCH (a:Person) WHERE a.userid ={userid} RETURN exists(a.userid)', 
      {userid: context.auth.uid})
    }

   return r as neo4j.v1.Result
  }

)

.then(result => {

    session.close();

    driver.close();

    if(result.records[0] == null){

      return    {
        "data": {
            "text": 0
        }
    }
    } else {
      return {
        "data": {
            "text": 1
        }
    }
    }


 })
 .catch(error => {
  session.close();
  console.log(error);
  driver.close()
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError(error,"some error");
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your top-level callback function isn't returning a promise that resolves with the value to send to the client after all the asynchronous work is complete.  In fact, it isn't returning any promise at all.  You will need to write your code such that it returns that promise to the client,  I suggest starting out with something much simpler in order to understand how it works.

Comment: Ok. `session.readTransaction` returns a promise and have put a `return` in front of it, now it works :) Thanks.